# Laravel widgets and widget boxes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a homepage in my application with a series of blocks that I have added by including them into the page using Blade syntax. All of these widgets using HTML and Bootstrap styling.

Each block is stored in a folder called Widgets and is essentially just a bunch of HTML as I've stated above.

E.g. `quick-search-form.blade.php`

```
<div class="grid-item element-item" tabindex="9">
    @include('widgets.events-cms')
</div>
```

I have the same blocks in a Widget Library that a user is supposed to be able to select from and then these widgets appear on the user's homepage.

Would this be something I could do with some tables?

**My conceptual idea**

A **widget** table that contains the IDs of the Widgets like `#quick-search` and that'd basically be it.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('widgets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('html_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

A **user_widget** table that contains a **user_id**, a **widget_id** and a **position**, representing the order to be displayed on the page.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_widgets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('widget_id');
        $table->integer('position')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then, within Laravel I'd set up a **one to many** from a user to widgets.

```
/**
 * Define that a User can have many widgets
 */
public function widgets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Widget::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Then I could use the following:**

```
$widgets = $user->widgets
```

**In the view**

```
@foreach($widgets as $widget)

    $widget->id

@endforeach
```

**My main concerns are:**

How would I get the HTML for the Widget via the ID?
When a user removes a Widget I could use AJAX but how would I decrement the position value?

Answer (score -1):

change this:

```
@foreach($widgets as $widget)

    $widget->id

@endforeach
```

to this:

```
@foreach($widgets as $widget)

    {!! $widget->id !!}

@endforeach
```